# list of subclasses of one of my classes

Tags: java, android, ios

Under Android environment, I need to list all subclasses of one of my classes.
I saw that there is samples with reading the directories.... But I would like to find them by asking to the Thread or application level or another running object.

Under iOS I use objc_getClassList and then I select the ones that I am interested in.

Dose someone know if there is a way to find a clean solution like objc_getClassList on generic java or specific android libraries?

Thanks in advance.
PS: All these classes I want to list are in a certain java package

Comment: For whome are interested to the question, I think that I underestood why it is not possible to ask to VM all present classes list. Because the VM doesn't know this list. Unlike objective C, in Java env. each Class is known only when it is invoked. The `static {instructions;}` sector is invoked only when you reference the class in run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure did I understand your question, but you could make a class called AllClasses or something, and in it put an ArrayList subclasses; and then in every subclass you have do 
       AllClasses.subclasses.add(this).

Thanks should do it

Comment: this loose  interest of the OOL.  I need this to add new functionalities for the user when a new subclass is present. Each time that a programmer add a subclass a new functionality appears! If it is not possible in Java we will do it like This (like a C Array of function pointers)!

Comment: finally I did something in your way:\`public class PortHelper {
 static ArrayList<Class<Port>> portSubclassList;
 static{
  portSubclassList= new ArrayList<Class<Port>>();
 }
 static public void addPortSubclass(Class<Port> c ){
  portSubclassList.add(c);
 }}\`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use introspection and the class loader to find out the classes and test if they are subtypes of a given super type. Here is an interesting implementation of your problem on J2SE : http://nonstop-rp.blogspot.fr/2010/05/java-reflection-know-subclasses-of.html

Comment: thank you for your answer, as it is it dose not turn under android environement. I will take the time to see why. It is exactly what I am looking for. Franckly said I thougth that this kind of functions is integrated to all OOL!